# Gem Permissions Issues

Tags: permissions, rubygems, rvm

I'm trying to install heroku taps for my app so i can pull the db.

```
gem install taps
```

I get an error

```
You don't have write permissions for the
     /Users/will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin directory
```

Iv'e had permissions errors all day as i updated OSX to 10.8.

If i try and

```
chown -R will ~/.rvm
```

I get a lot of "operation not permitted" errors for all the gems and their files.

eg

```
chown: /Users/will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/specifications/sprockets-2.2.2.gemspec: Operation not permitted
```

Why is this happening? And how do i pull my previously working ruby ecosystem into shape?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
rvmsudo rvm fix-permissions user
```

Comment: This works, just adding that it should be:  


```rvmsudo rvm fix-permissions [YOUR-USERNAME]```  



Otherwise it will fix permissions for root